# My nook HD won't charge

Tags: charging, nook, nook-hd

Unlike similar posts about this issue, the light doesn't from green to red to nothing when I plug it in, but rather, it just goes to green for a few seconds, and then nothing. I hadn't used it in a few years, and I went to use it again and this happened. I'm using the nook brand block and cable. It is a BNTV400. holding the power button for 20 seconds, or any length of time does not turn it on.

Answer (score 0):

oops, tried a different charger and it worked